# Polkadot.js extension detected but "no accounts has been injected" message

Tags: polkadot-js, staking, account

I am using chrome browser (ver. 122.0.6261.129) with polkadot.js extension.  Been able to access my account without issues for over 2.5 years to view my daily increases from staking polkadot.  For about last 2 weeks, I have been unable to view my account.  Maybe once a week, it will successfully complete the display of my account and then would not do so on the next attempt. I would get the no account has been injected message.

I am able to keep track of my daily staking rewards from the polkadot.subscan.io site.  How would I go about recovering my injected account on the js site?

Comment: Does your account show up correctly in the extension? Is it an account created on PJS or imported? The problem doesn't show up every time, right? Then it might be just a matter of the delay the browser has for loading up the info.